# Java ftp download status bar

Tags: java, ftp, statusbar

Hello i need a status bar for FTP download.
I would like to get a float <=1 with the progess. This is my code:

```
                float status=0;
                FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles(REMOTEFILE);
                if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();
                }
                long size = files[0].getSize();
                InputStream inputStream = ftp.retrieveFileStream(REMOTEFILE);
                byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                int download=0;
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0){
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                    download+=1024;
                    status=(float)download/size; // here it set the progress
                }
                out.close();
```

My trouble is that at the end status is more than 1 and I think is over the buffer size of 1024 (in case of not full buffer at the end). Maybe because downloaded bytes are more than how much files[0].getSize() gives to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add 1024 bytes to `download` no matter how many bytes are actually read. You already have a ref to the number of bytes read; `len` - use this instead.

Comment: From the javadoc; `Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer.`